# Cannot generate mapnik tiles on Fedora

Tags: postgis, postgresql, mapnik, apache

I have gone through the following tutorial to start a map server on Fedora 28:

https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Mapnik/Installation_on_Fedora_18

Although the tutorial is a bit old, most of the steps work fine. Basically we do the following:

1. Install and start postgresql-server and postgis
2. Create and setup database
   named `gis` and user name `apache` with all privileges granted on geometry_columns and spatial_ref_sys
3. Build osm2pgsql from source
4. Get a region data (in osm format)
5. Import the osm data into `gis` using `./osm2pgsql -S ./default.style ../region.osm`
6. Install mapnik:
   `yum install mapnik mapnik-devel mapnik-python proj-epsg`
7. Checkout mapnik data from source:
   `svn co http://svn.openstreetmap.org/applications/rendering/mapnik`
8. Download coatline data and some other data:

> wget http://tile.openstreetmap.org/world_boundaries-spherical.tgz wget
>   http://tile.openstreetmap.org/processed_p.tar.bz2 wget
>   http://tile.openstreetmap.org/shoreline_300.tar.bz2 wget
>   http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/cultural/ne_10m_populated_places.zip
>   wget
>   http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/110m/cultural/ne_110m_admin_0_boundary_lines_land.zip

9. Unpack files and setup mapnik environment.

> cd ~/osm/mapnik tar xvzf world_boundaries-spherical.tgz tar xvjf
>   processed_p.tar.bz2 -C world_boundaries tar xvjf shoreline_300.tar.bz2
>   -C world_boundaries unzip ne_10m-populated-places.zip -d world_boundaries unzip ne_110m-admin-0-boundary-lines_land.zip -d
>   world_boundaries cd ~/osm/mapnik cp archive/set-mapnik-env . vim
>   set-mapnik-env change "export MAPNIK_DBNAME='osm'" to 'gis' change
>   "export MAPNIK_DBUSER=`whoami`" to 'apache'

10. Run the script generate_tiles.py (A slightly modified version of it in fact).
    Almost all steps are successful on Fedora 28, except the last step which gives me the following error:

> [postgres@localhost mapnik]$ ./z0_generate_tiles.py 
>   /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/mapnik2/**init**.py:27:
>   DeprecationWarning:  mapnik2 module has been deprecated,
>           please use 'import mapnik'    warnings.warn(msg, DeprecationWarning) render_tiles( (-180.0, -90.0, 180.0, 90.0)
>   /var/lib/pgsql/mapnik/osm.xml /var/lib/pgsql/mapnik/tiles/ 0 0 World )
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File "./z0_generate_tiles.py",
>   line 215, in 
>       render_tiles(bbox, mapfile, tile_dir, 0, 0, "World")   File "./z0_generate_tiles.py", line 136, in render_tiles
>       renderer = RenderThread(tile_dir, mapfile, queue, printLock, maxZoom)   File "./z0_generate_tiles.py", line 64, in **init**
>       mapnik.load_map(self.m, mapfile, True) RuntimeError: XML document not well formed: Entity 'prefix' not defined at line 4064 of
>   '/var/lib/pgsql/mapnik/osm.xml'